# Bucle en arreglo de objetos. JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, objeto

Estoy empezando con objetos y me cuesta entender los recorridos.

Necesito devolver de este arreglo de objetos un arreglo de objeto con la propiedad indicada:

```js
let arreglo = [
  { name: "lucas", edad: 20 },
  { name: "santi", edad: 22 },
]
```

Lo encaré con **`for..in`** para ingresar al arreglo y luego de nuevo para recorrer cada objeto. Y sí dentro de ese recorrido se encuentra con la propiedad dada, si no es dicha propiedad, debería eliminarla.

Mi lógica me llevó a esta función:

```js
function unaPropiedad(array, string) {
  for (var i in array) {
    for (var j in array[i]) {
      if (array[i][j].hasOwnProperty(string) === false) {
        delete array[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  return array
}
```

Pero al hacer `oneProperty(arreglo, “edad”)` debería retornarme `[ { edad: 20 }, { edad: 22 } ]`

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo atacar esto?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dije en el comentario, te dejo una solución para que puedas mantener ambas variables(la nueva y la original) para tu disposición. Haciendo uso de la función *map* y la *Object.create()*

```js
const devolver = (arregloIn, campo) =>
  arregloIn.map((obj) => {
    newObj = Object.create(obj);
    newObj[campo] = obj[campo];
    return newObj;
  })

let arreglo = [
  {
    name: "lucas",
    edad: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "santi",
    edad: 22,
  },
];

console.log("Nuevo array:", devolver(arreglo, "name"));
console.log("Original", arreglo);
```

Comment: Gran solución. Justo estoy viendo esos conceptos de crear objetos a través de otros. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

> Pude llegar a la solución.

Les comparto el código:

```js
let arreglo = [
  { name: "lucas", edad: 20 },
  { name: "santi", edad: 22 },
]

function oneProperty(array, string) {
  for (let i in array) {
    for (let prop in array[i]) {
      if (prop != string) {
        delete array[i][prop];
      }
    }
  }

  return array
}
```

A través de dos **`for..in`** y con la variable que hace la segunda iteración la comparé con el **string** propuesta en la función. Si no son iguales debe eliminar la propiedad del objeto, tanto en el primero como en el segundo.

Y devolver el *array* con ambos objetos.

Comment: Que tal Ezequiel, bienvenido a S.O. Español. primero como sugerencia, te recomiendo que hagas un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio y ganes así tu primera medalla. también, para tus futuras preguntas, seria bueno que te des una vuelta por [ask] y mejorar así para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas.

Comment: Como comentario, es bueno saber que cualquier variable de tipo *Object* tiende a hacer referencia al la memoria donde este se encuentre.  Al eliminar un dato de esa variable haces una eliminación de la variable original por lo cual, si en algún futuro lo llegaras a necesitar, este ya estaría corrompido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información. Sí, tengo en cuenta el hecho de que estoy alterando los objetos del array original y con ello mi solución no es la mejor a fines prácticos.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que yo te traigo no sé si será más eficiente o te servirá de algo, pero yo afronté el problema de esta forma para evitar eliminar el arreglo base para así usarlo luego en el código si es necesario.

```js
let arregloBase = [
  { name: "lucas", edad: 20 },
  { name: "santi", edad: 22 },
];

function unaPropiedad(arrayBase, prop) {
  let arrayFinal = [];
  for (let i in arrayBase) {
    if (arrayBase[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      arrayFinal.push({
        name: arrayBase[i][prop],
      });
    }
  }

  return arrayFinal;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. Me gusta cómo lo encaraste. Y también pensé en esa forma. Aunque no se me pedía en el ejercicio mantener el array original. Al ser así lo pensé más bien como un .filter

Comment: También me di cuenta que con tú solución si se llegara a pedir en el segundo parámetro "edad" no me estaría devolviendo lo que necesita el ejercicio